# FIR filter design

Tags: matlab, filtering

Consider a white Gaussian noise process y[n]with variance σ2y=1.2, which is passed through a length-two finite impulse response filter g[n]with impulse response

```
 g[0]=2, g[1]=0.6,
```

and

```
   g[n]=0
   for all other n.
```

The resulting output process is:

```
   r[n] = g[n]*y[n] = ∑∞k=−∞ ( g[k] y[n−k] )
```

How would I go about designing the FIR filter in Matlab?

Comment: *sniff....sniff sniff sniff*.... smells like homework to me.

Comment: I would suggest that you start by looking at the information already provided by Mathworks on this very topic: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/fir-filter-design.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks more complicated than it actually is. With given `g` which in filter-terms is a `b` for IR-filters, it is quite easy to 'design' the filter. `b` is already the filter coefficient defining the whole filter. The following code opens the filter in the Filter Visualization Tool:

```
b = [2; 0.6];
fvtool(b,1)
```

To apply this filter use `filter`. To generate normally distributed noise use `randn` multiplicated by the standard deviation which is here `sqrt(1.2)`:

```
x = randn(1,100) * sqrt(1.2);
xf = filter(b,1,x);
```

`xf` is the filtered signal.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to determine the autocorrelation of function x(n) which is the result of r(n) + d(n) (this is an independent Gaussian noise process). No values are known but for those to values of g(n) and two variances: _sy= 1.2_ and _sd=0.2_. mathematically I deduced that then the autocorrelation function of x(n) is _Rxx = sy g(m) * g(-m) + sd delta(m)_. For this I want to use the function _xcorr_ in Matlab to determine that convolution but I don't know how to write g(m) and g(-m) in matlab.

Comment: @Daan Wabeke: Ok, this is what you want to do in the other post. But I answered the question of this post, so it would be nice to get an accepted answer here. Then, the next question can be solved in the other post where you asked for it.

Comment: sorry, i'm new to this website, you did answer my question, thanks for that. What do you mean by accepted answer?

Comment: got it, sorry for my confusion. I'm still having trouble though because my problem is implementing g(m). What I have done now is simply use a vector [2 0.6] but that doesn't seem to be right.